# Maven plugin for creating an *.exe file

Tags: java, maven, exe

I want create *.exe file for my project with Maven. I use `launch4j-maven-plugin` and it works, but it need format of `fileVersion` and `productVersion` as "x.x.x.x". I need `fileVersion` as "x.x.x" and `productVersion` as "x.x.x.x". Can I change this format?
My pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>com.akathist.maven.plugins.launch4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>launch4j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>l4j-clui</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>launch4j</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <headerType>gui</headerType>
                        <jar>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-jar-with-dependencies.jar</jar>
                        <outfile>${project.build.directory}/${exeFileName}.exe</outfile>
                        <downloadUrl>http://java.com/download</downloadUrl>
                        <classPath>
                            <mainClass>MainClass</mainClass>
                            <preCp>anything</preCp>
                        </classPath>
                        <icon>${project.basedir}/src/main/assembly/application.ico</icon>
                        <jre>
                            <minVersion>1.7.0_00</minVersion>
                            <jdkPreference>preferJre</jdkPreference>
                        </jre>
                        <versionInfo>
                            <fileVersion>${project.version}.${buildNumber}</fileVersion>
                            <txtFileVersion>txtFileVersion</txtFileVersion>
                            <fileDescription>${product.name}</fileDescription>
                            <copyright>${project.organization.name}</copyright>
                            <productVersion>${project.version}</productVersion>
                            <txtProductVersion>txtProductVersion</txtProductVersion>
                            <productName>${product.name}</productName>
                            <companyName>${product.company}</companyName>
                            <internalName>abc</internalName>
                            <originalFilename>${exeFileName}.exe</originalFilename>
                        </versionInfo>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

My exception:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.akathist.maven.plugins.launch4j:launch4j-maven-plugin:1.5.2:launch4j (l4j-clui) on project MyProject: Failed to build the executable; please verify your configuration. Invalid data: File version, should be 'x.x.x.x'
```

May be another maven plugin exists for create *.exe file?

Answer (score 0):

try mvn assembly:single. It is specifically used for creation of executable jar file.

Also you need to configure this plugin in your pom.xml

Comment: I use it for creating jar, but I want to create *.exe file.

Comment: see you have told you need to create an executable jar in your question and you may use the above plugin.

Comment: I wrote executable file, not jar. Corrected. As I know maven-assembly-plugin can not set fileVersion.